# Bind RadcomboBox with multiple columns from Datatable

Tags: asp.net, telerik

I would like to bind 'Id', 'Name' and 'Email' from DataTable to RadComboBox. It's possible with ItemTemplate. But I don't want to display 'Email' column in the RadComboBox. I want display 'Email' in the label when the selectedIndexChanged. Is this possible?

Thank you..

Comment: There tends to be more answers if you up your answer rate...

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you can bind these three items within the RadComboBox by using the template.  Check out this demo: http://demos.telerik.com/aspnet-ajax/combobox/examples/functionality/templates/defaultcs.aspx

Also, to display email when an item is selected, set the DataTextField="Email", which is the value that should appear when the selection is made.

HTH.

Answer (score 0):

adding custom attributes to the RadComboBox is also a good option.

```
    protected void RadComboBox_ItemsRequested(object sender, Telerik.Web.UI.RadComboBoxItemsRequestedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            RadComboBox myRadComboBox = (RadComboBox)sender;

            _rowsOfData = Db.getPeopleOfInterest();

            foreach (row _row in _rowsOfData)
            {
                RadComboBoxItem item = new RadComboBoxItem
                {
                    Text = _row.Name,
                    Value = _row.Id.ToString()
                };

                string eMail = _row.Email;
                item.Attributes.Add("Email", Email);
                item.DataBind();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            HandleException(ex, true);
        }

    }
```

Then to display that on the GUI just use something like :

```
<td>
<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container, "Attributes['Name']")%>
</td>
```